# How to Change default password for aws ec2 instance remote desktop connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, remote-desktop, change-password

I have a Windows AWS EC2 instance. I can connect to my windows server using Remote Desktop with password using the Decryption of aws ec2 key pair. Now my question is, how do i change the password ? Do i delete the old key pair and create new one ? or is there any ways that i don't need to stop my instance.

Thank You

Comment: Just use the standard Windows Computer Management UI, aka compmgmt.msc, to change the password for the admin user.

Comment: How are you deploying the EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

When a new Amazon EC2 instance is launched with the Windows operating system, a script generates a random password for the `Administrator` user. This ensures that nobody else can login to your instance.

It then encrypts the password so that it can only be decrypted by somebody who has the `GetPasswordData` permission.

You are welcome (and encouraged!) to change this `Administrator` password when you first login. You can If you are in a company, then it would be best to connect the instance to your Active Directory server so that you can login using your normal corporate login.

Random example: [How to change the password in Windows Server 2022 - FineRDP](https://finerdp.com/blog/how_to_change_password_windows_server_2022)

Comment: If i change the password from the windows, will it affect the key pair decryption ? e.g : If i do EC2 console> select instance > Connect > RDP Client > Get password > Paste key pair > Decrypt Password, will the password still show default password or show the new password that i have change from the windows computer management ?

Comment: It will show the generated password.  The password you enter is not stored anywhere in a form that can be displayed.

Comment: so after i change the administrator password, when i want to connect using RDP, will use the new password i created ?